# TikZ: using a bitmaps's dimensions as global bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, bitmap

I'm [using a tikzpicture environment to draw on a bitmap image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz) in order to add annotations. I'm setting the width of my bitmap to `\textwidth.` I want to add annotations in the left or right margins of the page. TikZ usually first completes the `tikzpicture,` then aligns it with the left margin. So what's required here is a manual bounding box to make sure it's the bitmap rather than the whole drawing that's left-aligned.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,12em);         % <------- !
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {%
    \rule{\textwidth}{12em}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[red,-latex] (-0.05,0.7) node[anchor=east] {abc} -- (0.5,0.9);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}\par
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This is all fine as long as we know the bitmap's dimensions, particulary its height. But -- is there a way to make tikz use the bitmap's dimensions (after my scaling it to `width=\textwidth`) as a bounding box for the entire drawing without us knowing them in advance?

Comment: `\newlength{\bitmapwd}\settowidth{\bitmapwd}{\includegraphics{...}}` and then use `\bitmapwd`

Comment: obviously...  how embarassing :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following code to your preamble

```
\newlength{\bitmapwd}
```

and then before the TikZ picture, type

```
\settowidth{\bitmapwd}{\includegraphics[...]{...}}
```

where the `\includegraphics` command should be the same you use for printing the image. In the TikZ picture you can use `\bitmapwd` for a length equal to what you need.